# Deploy Azure Data Factory Pipelines through GitLab

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, azure-data-factory

How to set up CI/CD pipelines for Azure Data Factory in GitLab. Can we deploy Data Factory through GitLab. Can someone please share useful links/documents for the same. TIA!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackk Overflow! You can pretty much do anything from a GitLab pipeline that you can do using the command-line. If you provide more information regarding a specific problem you're trying to solve, including steps you've tried and where you are stuck, we can help out more. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ DV82XL Thanks for your reply. I am new to GitLab and have earlier deployed ADF pipelines through Azure DevOps. I am trying to deploy Azure Resource Manager(ARM) templates through GitLab and looking for step by step procedure for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately, Azure Data Factory doesn't support Gitlab.

Currently, Azure Data Factory allows you to configure a Git repository with either Azure DevOps or GitHub.

**Reference:** [Continuous integration and delivery in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment)

I would suggest you to vote up an idea submitted by another Azure customer.

https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/aa3d7da4-6f26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.